Searching For An Artist's Lyrics Using Genius API
I am currently trying to get the Genius API running. Right now, I am trying to access a list of the artist's songs. Previously, my code would search when I ran it but now it is not loading. I figured maybe it was an issue with my API Key but when I generated a new key, I was still receiving the same error message. I even ensured the api key was valid using curl -H.
import lyricsgenius 
GENIUS_ACCESS = os.getenv('GENIUS_ACCESS')
genius = lyricsgenius.Genius(GENIUS_ACCESS)
genius.search_artist("Drake")

The output of this Code is
Searching for songs by Drake...

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lyricsgenius/api/base.py:80, in Sender._make_request(self, path, method, params_, public_api, web, **kwargs)
     75     response = self._session.request(method, uri,
     76                                      timeout=self.timeout,
     77                                      params=params_,
     78                                      headers=header,
     79                                      **kwargs)
---> 80     response.raise_for_status()
     81 except Timeout as e:

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py:1021, in Response.raise_for_status(self)
   1020 if http_error_msg:
-> 1021     raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)

HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://genius.com/api/search/multi?q=Drake

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [27], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 genius.search_artist("Drake")

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lyricsgenius/genius.py:519, in Genius.search_artist(self, artist_name, max_songs, sort, per_page, get_full_info, allow_name_change, artist_id, include_features)
    516     return found_artist['id']
    518 # Get the artist ID (or use the one supplied)
--> 519 artist_id = artist_id if artist_id else find_artist_id(artist_name)
    520 if not artist_id:
    521     return None

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lyricsgenius/genius.py:504, in Genius.search_artist.<locals>.find_artist_id(search_term)
    502 # Perform a Genius API search for the artist
    503 found_artist = None
--> 504 response = self.search_all(search_term)
    505 found_artist = self._get_item_from_search_response(response,
    506                                                    search_term,
    507                                                    type_="artist",
    508                                                    result_type="name")
    510 # Exit the search if we couldn't find an artist by the given name

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lyricsgenius/api/public_methods/search.py:210, in SearchMethods.search_all(self, search_term, per_page, page)
    188 """Searches all types.
    189 
    190 Including: albums, articles, lyrics, songs, users and
   (...)
    207 
    208 """
    209 endpoint = 'multi'
--> 210 return self.search(search_term, per_page, page, endpoint)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lyricsgenius/api/public_methods/search.py:45, in SearchMethods.search(self, search_term, per_page, page, type_)
     41     path = 'search/' + type_
     42 params = {'q': search_term,
     43           'per_page': per_page,
     44           'page': page}
---> 45 return self._make_request(path, params_=params, public_api=True)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lyricsgenius/api/base.py:88, in Sender._make_request(self, path, method, params_, public_api, web, **kwargs)
     86     error = get_description(e)
     87     if response.status_code < 500 or tries > self.retries:
---> 88         raise HTTPError(response.status_code, error) from e
     90 # Enforce rate limiting
     91 time.sleep(self.sleep_time)

HTTPError: [Errno 403] 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://genius.com/api/search/multi?q=Drake


Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?: "Questions where you're getting some sort of bad credential response (i.e. "This account can't login" or "Your password is incorrect"), or a general login error (i.e. "An error occurred, try again later"), will need direct customer support from that company, as the error is either on their end, or you need something fixed with your account. We cannot debug an external service for you."
